# What kind of small succulent is this?

Tags: houseplants

The plant totals 4 inches high to the top of the flower stalks. The leaves are thin but fleshy. The leaves are in rosettes. The leaves are pinkish red on the bottom and green on top. The flowers are fragrant but not nice. Thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: I'm thinking a Kalanchoe. Very floriferous plant.

Comment: I searched a lot of websites with both Kalanchoe and Haworthia and found a lot of similar looking plants but nothing quite right. I saw a mention of an app for the phone called Google Lens. I tried it and it showed me matching pictures of Crassula orbicularis var. rosularis. Crassula orbicularis by itself doesn't match but the variety does. Thank you, Yosef for your effort.

Comment: Yes, Crassula orbicularis var. rosularis looks exactly right.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, You should make it an answer with links to that reference.